# what is the mechanism for performing an intersect in a Mongo Linq query

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

How do I write a where clause in Linq for Mongo to determine if any member of a local collection is contained by a collection in my document.

i.e.  (this was what I was expecting to work, but didn't)

```
var myLocalList = <PopulateMyLocalList>;

var myDocs = db.GetCollection<MyDoc>("MyDocs").AsQueryable();
var result =  myDocs.Where(d => d.MyCollection.Intersect(myLocalList).Any());
```

So assuming that the Mongo Linq provider does not support this - How do I go about it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In MongoDB syntax there's a [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/index.html) operator which works exactly like intersect+any when you want to match an in-memory array with another array embedded in your document.

> If the field holds an array, then the $in operator selects the documents whose field holds an array that contains **at least one element** that matches a value in the specified array (e.g. , , etc.)

In MongoDB C# driver you can use `AnyIn` to apply that operator for two arrays. Try:

```
db.col.save({ Collection: [1,2,3] })l
```

Then in C#:

```
var filterBuilder = Builders<YourModel>.Filter;
var inMemoryList = new List<int>() { 3, 4, 5 };

var result = Col.Find(filterBuilder.AnyIn(x => x.Collection, inMemoryList)).ToList();
```

Comment: Nice one dude !