# MongoDB Linq query including list of objects as paramters

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to create a MongoDB LINQ query by passing a list of objects as a parameter. I am passing to the method IEnumerable collection:

```
    IEnumerable<(double latitude, double longitude)> coords
```

And I am building the following query:

```
var q =
    GetDbCollection()
        .AsQueryable()
        .Where(x => coords.Any(c => x.Longitude == c.longitude && x.Latitude == c.latitude))
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
        .Take(coords.Count());
```

`GetDbCollection()` has the following implementation:

```
internal IMongoCollection<T> GetDbCollection(string name = "")  
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name)) name = typeof(T).Name;
    var client = new MongoClient(_dbContext.ConnectionString);      
    var database = client.GetDatabase(_dbContext.DatabaseName);
    var collection = database.GetCollection<T>(name);
    return collection;
}
```

This part of a query isn't working:

```
Where(x => coords.Any(c => x.Longitude == c.longitude && x.Latitude == c.latitude))
```

I am getting the following exception:

> Unsupported filter: Any(value(System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectListIterator`2[Models.Coordinate,System.ValueTuple`2[System.Double,System.Double]]).Where((({document}{Longitude} == {document}{Item2}) AndAlso ({document}{Latitude} == {document}{Item1})))).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this implementation solves the issue

```
        List<FilterDefinition<Models.Forecast>> filters = new List<FilterDefinition<Models.Forecast>>();

        foreach (var item in coords)
        {
            var filterBuilder = Builders<Models.Forecast>.Filter.Where(x => x.Latitude == item.latitude && x.Longitude == item.longitude);
            filters.Add(filterBuilder);
        }

        var filterDefinition = Builders<Models.Forecast>.Filter.Or(filters);
        var q = GetDbCollection()
            .Find(filterDefinition)
            .SortByDescending(x => x.Date)
            .Limit(coords.Count());
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in this answer: [micki's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51959853/what-is-the-mechanism-for-performing-an-intersect-in-a-mongo-linq-query), you can use `AnyIn` to perform this task

Comment: As I see, AnyIn is working with a single value type collection on a single document field. I need to iterate through collection of (double, double) and compare two document fields and if possible do this in a single request.